# glfwCreateWindow breaks gdb session, emiting SIGSTOP signal

Tags: c, opengl, gdb, glfw

I use gdb debugger on Ubuntu OS for debugging my application.
I can't pass through `glfwCreateWindow` function, during debug session.
My debug session is broken by `SIGSTOP` signal, when I'm doing step over from `glfwCreateWindow` to next code string:

```
glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);
if (!glfwInit())
{
    printf("Couldn't init GLFW \n");
    return -1;
}
GLFWwindow* window = nullptr;
//glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
//glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
//glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
//glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
//glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_DEBUG_CONTEXT, GLFW_TRUE);
window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
if (!window)
{
    glfwTerminate();
    printf("Couldn't open window \n");
    return -1;
}
// Make the window's context current
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
```

I would like to do step over action from `glfwCreateWindow` function during debug session.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: where exactly does SIGSTOP occur? if you continue the debug session does it work?

Comment: My debug session is broken by SIGSTOP signal immediately after i have done step over from glfwCreateWindow to next code string. Debug session doesn't continue.

Comment: SIGSTOP pauses a program and does not end it permanently. In fact I think debuggers use SIGSTOP deliberately to pause the program you are debugging. So I would look at: at what exact line of code (inside glfw) is the program paused, and why does the debugger say it's paused

Comment: I use release version of glfw. i will try to compile debug version

Comment: I couldn't compile debug version of glfw, but i noticed that my QT Creator shows disassembler code at point clone.S after end of session